# How to test a ternary operator with Jest in Angular

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jestjs, ts-jest

I have this code, and I want to test headerBackBtn with ternary operator `this.headerBackBtnLabel ? true : false;`.

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'app-page-header',
    templateUrl: './page-header.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./page-header.component.scss']
})
export class PageHeaderComponent {
    @Input() actions: IIcon[] = [];

    @Input() title!: string;

    @Input() headerBackBtnLabel = '';

    @Input() headerBackBtn = this.headerBackBtnLabel ? true : false; //◄◄◄

    @Output() actionClickName = new EventEmitter();

    actionClick(actionName: string): void {
        this.actionClickName.emit(actionName);
    }
}
```

I have this test ▼, but still test coverage shows that I am not covering ternary branch (see img)

```js
    it('should render header back button element when there is BackBtnLabel', () => {
        component.headerBackBtnLabel = 'Any Button Label';
        component.headerBackBtn = Boolean(component.headerBackBtnLabel);
        fixture.detectChanges();
        const compiledElement = fixture.debugElement.query(
            By.css('.action-btn-label')
        );

        expect(component.headerBackBtn).toEqual(true);
        expect(compiledElement).toBeTruthy();
    });
```

[image]

How to fix this? I searched and tried a lot but still failing to solve :/

I can avoid branching by using `@Input() headerBackBtn = Boolean(this.headerBackBtnLabel)` but this is not a fix but just a workaround...

Comment: Fundamentally I don't think that works how you think it does. You're not connecting those two values together, you're setting a default value for one based on the (empty string) default value of the other. The true branch is unreachable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @jonrsharpe and @Arnaud Denoyelle mentioned there were some issues with code. I've checked and I agree with @jonrsharpe "The true branch is unreachable". When `@Input() headerBackBtnLabel` is updated it doesn't update `@Input() headerBackBtn`'s default value, thus `headerBackBtn` stays false until not directly changed with `true` by its `@Input`.

Answer (score 1):

I see 2 ways of doing this :

1. **Use the `!!` syntax in the html template**

You want to replace the property with `true` if the value is non empty and `false` if the value is empty. The double negation syntax will do that.

- The first negation will invert the value and cast it to a boolean.
- The second negation will re-invert the value and keep it as a boolean

```html
<div *ngIf="!!headerBackBtnLabel"> Display the button</div>
```

2. **Use the setter syntax on the input**

Like this :

```js
headerBackBtn: boolean
_headerBackBtnLabel: string

@Input() set headerBackBtnLabel(label: string) {
  this._headerBackBtnLabel = label;
  this.headerBackBtn = !!label;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but this is a workaround. I want to know how to test ternary branching. I am sure there must be a way.

Comment: @Dan there seems to be a bug in the code. It looks weird that property `headerBackBtn` depends on `headerBackBtnLabel` and, in the same time, can be set via an `@Input` on the component. Does it make sense that I could write `<app-component [headerBackBtnLabel]="" [headerBackBtn]="true">`. imho, the way it is written provokes an undefined behavior, depending on which property is evaluated first. The problem you encounter might come from there.

Comment: There are cases when you don't need label, but by providing [headerBackBtn]="true", back button will appear.

Comment: @Dan Problem : there are case where you can set `headerBackBtn` to true and, because given label is empty, the `headerBackBtn` will be back to `false` (depending on the order of execution of the `@Input`) : see example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xrej7f?file=src/app/app.component.html). imho, it is safer to just accept `@Input` as is and not modify them. Then, in the template, use `*ngIf="headerBackBtn || !!headerBackBtnLabel"`

Comment: Now agree, thanks.